# Any dataprovider available for specflow

Tags: mstest, specflow

Looking for data provider as external file like CSV/Excel, similar to MsTest Unit testing framework. Anybody tried or Any implementation available?

Answer (score 2):

I would wrote a separate method, which would read data from csv/excel file in needed order. And added this method in the step, to call it after from Scenario.
Also, in non-free [SpecFlow+](https://specflow.org/plus/documentation/SpecFlowPlus-Excel/) version has plugin for reading from Excel.